# JLabel rendering intermittent font size issue

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I am using a JLabel to render some basic HTML text onto a Graphics2D canvas in an application. This is an image processing application and has no user interface.

```
    private void renderHtmlText(String text, Graphics2D g, Font f) {
        JLabel label = new JLabel(text);
        label.setFont(f);
        
        if(isWrapText()) {
            label.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(wrapWidth, 1000));
        }
        label.setSize(label.getPreferredSize());
        g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(newFont.getSize() / 10));
        label.paint(g);
    }
```

My problem is that intermittent the label gets rendered with much smaller font size. This is a transient issue. I understand that `setFont` and `setSize`, etc dispatch an event to a separate thread for processing, but I don't see how could I synchronize with the end of those events to start my `paint` call.

What's the right approach for this?c

Comment: Either do your painting on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html), or paint to a [BufferedImage](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) and paint the BufferedImage on the Event Dispatch Thread.  Don't use a JLabel.  Use a drawing JPanel.

Comment: *I understand that setFont and setSize, etc dispatch an event to a separate thread* - no they don't. Those methods execute on the current Thread. However all updates to a Swing components SHOULD execute on the `Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)`. If not, then you can get random results.

Comment: Swing painting is optimized.  In addition to following Gilbert’s and camickr’s advice regarding the event dispatch thread, you should use [SwingUtilities.paintComponent](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics,java.awt.Component,java.awt.Container,int,int,int,int)), rather than calling label.paint(g) directly.

Comment: My code is executed inside a larger application and I don't have control over the threads. @GilbertLeBlanc - JLabel can deal with basic HTML, how can I replace that with JPanel that cannot do that? `SwingUtilities.paintComponent` seems to be exactly what I need, I'll just need to figure out the correct usage. Thank you all for your invaluable help!

Comment: @VGR I am looking at the source of `SwingUtilities.paintComponent` but I don't see any significant different from a threading perspective compared to my current unreliable approach. It eventually calls `paint` of JLabel similarly on the same thread, so I think this would also suffer from my intermittent issue. Although in `SwingUtilities` I can see methods such as `invokeAndWait` which might give me the desired reliability